# pip install pods command failed in jupyter with FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\tmp\\sods.log'

Tags: python, anaconda, package, jupyter

I tried installing the pods package in jupyter notebook using the below commands:

```
   pip install pods 

   import pods
```

Installation failed with the following error

```
       ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-3-c6cba4dfa9c3> in <module>
      1 get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')
----> 2 import pods
      3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pods\__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from . import datasets
      2 from . import mocap

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pods\datasets.py in <module>
     17 import logging
     18 
---> 19 logging.basicConfig(
     20     level=logging.DEBUG,
     21     format="%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s",

~\anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py in basicConfig(**kwargs)
   1974                 mode = kwargs.pop("filemode", 'a')
   1975                 if filename:
-> 1976                     h = FileHandler(filename, mode)
   1977                 else:
   1978                     stream = kwargs.pop("stream", None)

~\anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py in __init__(self, filename, mode, encoding, delay)
   1141             self.stream = None
   1142         else:
-> 1143             StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
   1144 
   1145     def close(self):

 ~\anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py in _open(self)
   1170         Return the resulting stream.
   1171         """
-> 1172         return open(self.baseFilename, self.mode, encoding=self.encoding)
   1173 
   1174     def emit(self, record):


 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\tmp\\sods.log'
```

I tried to install the pods package with `! pip install pods --user` command but still, the issue is the same. Could anyone give your insights for solving the issue?

Comment: Looks like `c:\\tmp` is used as a hard coded path for writing logs. Have you tried creating that folder?

Comment: I tried creating the folder and it executed successfully. Thank you

Comment: I posted it as an answer so you can mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the path for the log file is hard coded in the source code, as can be seen on [github](https://github.com/sods/ods/blob/3b91f06c649ec9bcb7ea2a37b8aa217643a2dd3f/pods/datasets.py#L22). The path `C:\\tmp` does however not exist per default in windows.

Simplest solution is just to create a tmp folder on your C drive